# Scroll bar no longer appearing

Tags: css, angular

The scroll bar in my app has suddenly vanished and I can't understand why. I have configured the scroll bar in my style.css file on my Angular app. It was there about an hour ago and I haven't changed anything in the any of the other css files. Does anyone know how to make it re-appear?!

[image]

There should be a scroll bar on the right hand side

Here is the styles.css file:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
  }

  /* Track */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }

  /* Handle */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: black;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
```

This is the gallery list css file. This is the component that is being displayed in the image below the header:

```
ul {
    margin:0 10px 0 0;
    padding:0;   
}

li { list-style: none; }

.item-list-container {
    column-count: 4;
    column-gap: 1.1em;
    margin-top: 107px;   
}
```

Gallery-list html file:

```
<ul class="container">
    <li class="item-list-container oneSec">
        <app-image-item
          *ngFor="let imageEl of galleryList"
          [image]="imageEl"
          (click)="onImageSelect(imageEl.id)"
          (click)="onLike(imageEl.imagePath)">
        </app-image-item>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Does the page get scrolled? And did you try decreasing the height of the div or the container which needed to be scrolled

Comment: Thanks for your response. The page doesn't get scrolled and the height of the container div isn't set and has never been set

Comment: Could you check if you haven't added `overflow: hidden` anywhere?

Comment: It would be better if you could edit the question and enter the html file of the gallery-list component, in order to get a clear understanding

Comment: I haven't added overflow: hidden. I've just updated the post

Answer (score 0):

Try to decrease the height of the li tag

```
<ul class="container">
        <li class="item-list-container oneSec" style="height: 200px">
            <app-image-item
              *ngFor="let imageEl of galleryList"
              [image]="imageEl"
              (click)="onImageSelect(imageEl.id)"
              (click)="onLike(imageEl.imagePath)">
            </app-image-item>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Because sometimes the scroll bar only appears when the container is small in height and it has more items

Comment: This just cuts of the bottom half of the first row of images unfortuantely